# Hashcat solving truncated hashes

Tags: password-cracking, hashcat

In hashcat, how does one specify that the given hashes have been reduced to a specific length? I.e. the stored hashes that are to be solved are truncated versions of what the hash function provides?

Comment: I'm looking for this as well.  I do see that type 5100 ("Half MD5") exists, so `hashcat -a3 -m5100 <(printf 9 |md5sum |head -c16) '?d'` correctly outputs `45c48cce2e2d7fbd:9`, but I can't get it to work with lengths other than 16 (`-m5100`) and 32 (`-m0`).  It probably requires messing with the source code.  That said, if you're looking for a MD5 length between 16 and 32, you can truncate the hash to 16 and only slightly increase the chance of an invalid collision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the current version (3.30), hashcat does not currently support truncated hashes beyond the half-MD5 modes. In my discussions with the team, I made the pitch (basically what I wrote [here](https://roycebits.blogspot.com/2015/10/hash-filtering-more-than-vanity.html)).

So far, they have expressed non-interest in expanding partial-hash matching to other types, as it's considered to be out of scope for the project. But this could change in the future.

Comment: Is there any Gpu accelerated solution to this?

Comment: In practice, as you discovered in Pornin's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5142984/263879), GPU-accelerated half-MD5 in hashcat would be sufficient to cover lengths higher than MD5 ... but in practice won't help much (for brute force, anyway)

Comment: Update 2018-10: It's not hashcat, so not a strict answer to the question, but for general truncated-hash work, [MDXfind](https://hashes.org/mdxfind.php) works on a variety of truncated hashes. It is currently CPU only, but that may change in the future.